# On the integral $-\int\log\left(\binom{1-x}{6}+\binom{x}{6}\right)dx$, and its definite integral over the unit interval

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, binomial-coefficients, closed-form

While I was playing with Wolfram Alpha online calculator I wondered that I know how to calculate with the help of this tool and my knowledges the first cases for integers $n\geq 1$ of this type of integral $$-\int_0^1\log\left(\binom{1-x}{n}+\binom{x}{n}\right)dx$$
and the corresponding indefinite integrals, where $\binom{a}{b}=\frac{a!}{b!(b-a)!}$ with $a!=\Gamma(a+1)$.

> **Question.** Is it possible to find $$-\int\log\left(\binom{1-x}{6}+\binom{x}{6}\right)dx$$
>   in terms of standard mathematical functions? And is it possible to get the closed-form of the corresponding real part of such integral over the unit interval, that is
>   $$-\int_0^1\Re\log\left(\binom{1-x}{6}+\binom{x}{6}\right)dx\,?$$
>   Justify your words. **Many thanks.**

Answer (score 1):

With CAS help like `Maple 2018`  it possible to get the closed-form of the integral:

$$\int_0^1 \Re(\ln (\binom{1-x}{6}+\binom{x}{6})) \, dx= \pi\,\sqrt {103-8\,\sqrt {151}}+\pi\,\sqrt {103+8\,\sqrt {151}}-2
\,\sqrt {103-8\,\sqrt {151}}\arctan \left( \sqrt {103-8\,\sqrt {151}}
 \right) -2\,\sqrt {103+8\,\sqrt {151}}\arctan \left( \sqrt {103+8\,
\sqrt {151}} \right) -\ln  \left( 5 \right) -6
$$

Code:

```
evala(Re(int(ln(convert(binomial(1-x, 6)+binomial(x, 6), elementary)), x = 0 .. 1)));

#Pi*sqrt(103-8*sqrt(151))+Pi*sqrt(103+8*sqrt(151))-2*sqrt(103- 8*sqrt(151))*arctan(sqrt(103- 
#8*sqrt(151)))-2*sqrt(103+8*sqrt(151))*arctan(sqrt(103+8*sqrt(151)))-ln(5)-6
```

Maple can find for $n>7$, if n value is getting bigger the solutions is very complicated(bigger).

Example: for n=8 solution is written on 20 pages!.

Comment: Many thanks for your attention and so cool work.